# Creating a WLAN to connect Android smartphones to Internet

Tags: wireless-networking

I am in a remote location in my summer cabin but catch the neighbour'
s WLAN with his permission via a TP-Link antenna placed in the focal point of a kitchen sieve at the signal's fringe, 20 m from my cabin. This contraption is connected to my laptop via a USB extension cable, the signal strength is then good (4 out of 5 bars). What do I need to do to share this Internet connection with a smartphone I plan to bring along next time? It will be an Android, and reading other blogs I sense there might be problems. Thanks to any techie who can help, I am not such an expert.

Answer (score 1):

You could...

- enable Internet Connection Sharing (if you are using a version of Windows) on your laptop, designate the wireless as the source, and share the connection to the Ethernet port on your laptop.  Then connect an Ethernet cable to one of the regular ports on a standard Wireless Router.  Change the router settings to Bridge Mode... essentially making it just an Access Point, passing the internet connection to any device that is connected to it, whether by wireless or wired.  With this option however, you would have to have the laptop on and connected to share the internet with your smart phone.
- purchase a wireless repeater that has removable antennae, and connect a separate external antennae to one channel.  Put that external antenna where the TP-Link device is, and the repeater would pick up your neighbor's wireless and rebroadcast it at your cabin.  This would be a stand-alone option, and would provide you with internet access on all your devices.

Now.  There are variations on these, but that's essentially your two options.  For example, you could shop around for Wireless Routers that have removable antennae, and check the [DD-WRT router Database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) to find one that is compatible with the DD-WRT firmware, to change the functionality of the router.  Why?  Because you could purchase a relatively inexpensive wireless router, turn it into a device that will also function as a repeater, and put an external antenna on it.  That's essentially the same as the second option, except you aren't purchasing a wireless repeater directly.

Comment: Thanks, sounds easy - there are cheap bridge/repeater devices and perhaps I stay with the brand I am using successfully. I just hope the Android smartphone will ot give me trouble in setting this up...